# Как правильно настроить CallbackQueryHandler? (aiogram)

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем здравствуйте, возникла такая проблема: aiogram выдает ошибку

```
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object
```

При попытке привязать Inline клавиатуру к сообщению, клавиатуры находятся в другом файле, нужная объявлена так:

```py
cancel = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❌ Отмена', callback_data='cancel')]])
```

Телеграм ее спокойно выводит, до того момента, пока я не создаю обработчик для нее (CallbackQueryHandler), выглядит он так:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='cancel')
async def cancel(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.edit_text(text='Отменено')
```

Вопрос: как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2):

```
cancel = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❌ Отмена', callback_data='cancel')]])
```

Поменяйте на

```
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❌ Отмена', callback_data='cancel'))
```

Так наверняка запустится. Хотя у меня ваш код работает